# Insuficient privileges on Apex_200200 tables

Tags: oracle, cloud

i tried to update table wwv_flow_item_list in Oracle autonomus database on cloud but i get error insuficient privileges. I cant even select data from those tables (all wwv prefix). User is ADMIN. which user have rights to perform these tasks ?

Comment: It seems unlikely that you want to make a direct update a table owned by Oracle so I'd question what problem you're actually trying to solve.  ADMIN is a common APEX username but not a common Oracle username.  Database privileges are given to Oracle users.  What Oracle user are you actually using?

Comment: @JustinCave If OP is using the Free Tier of the Oracle Cloud, the administrative user for the Database is ADMIN, unlike with normal installations where you have sys/system and such.

Question still is, and here I agree with you, why is he trying to update an APEX table?

Comment: @JustinCave Thanks for response, it is table which is posible to update through apex shared components. I dont have even select privilege as admin user .Owner is user Apex_200200 and table is used for different properties of page like authorization etc. User ADMIN is not apex user its Oracle database user becouse sys is not available on cloud. On premise it is posible but not on cloud.

Comment: @EdwardKirk Not just an update, i cant select also. On premise it is posible but when i migrated on cloud it is not. I need to update apex table becouse : they contain data about diferent properties like page properties and to make custom form to modify those properties, some of them is posible through packages and procedures but not on this one table.